# Java JNA: PROCESSENTRY32.szExeFile returns "????..." when converted to a Java string

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I'm new to JNA and upon attempting my first program to list all processes on Windows I've run into a bit of trouble. For some reason, I get the following output:

```
[pid = 0, name = ???????? ]
[pid = 4, name = ???????? ]
[pid = 364, name = ???????? ]
[pid = 516, name = ????e??? ]
[pid = 648, name = ?????e?? ]
[pid = 668, name = ????ee?? ]
[pid = 708, name = ???????? ]
[pid = 732, name = ????e??? ]
[pid = 740, name = ???ee??? ]
[pid = 796, name = ???????? ]
[pid = 880, name = ?????e?? ]
...
```

The process identifiers were valid and were currently running on my system during the snapshot, but for some reason the strings got corrupted. Several other similar examples on StackOverflow gave me the same result. Do I need to specify something new in the latest version of JNA to get such a procedure to work?

```
    public class Processes 
    {
        private static final Kernel32 kernel = ( Kernel32 )Native.loadLibrary( Kernel32.class );

        public static ArrayList<Process> getSnapshot( ) throws LastErrorException
        {
            ArrayList<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>( );
            HANDLE snapshot = null;

            try
            {
                snapshot = kernel.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( Tlhelp32.TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, new DWORD( 0 ) );
                PROCESSENTRY32 entry = new PROCESSENTRY32( );
                kernel.Process32First( snapshot, entry );

                do
                {
                    processes.add( new Process( Native.toString( entry.szExeFile ), entry.th32ProcessID.intValue() ) );
                }
                while( kernel.Process32Next( snapshot, entry ) );
            }
            finally
            {
                kernel.CloseHandle( snapshot );
            }

            return processes;
        }
    }
```

My code is based heavily off of the MSDN example featured [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Is this a 32 bit process on a 64 bit system?

Comment: Btw, resource acquisition should come before `try`.

Comment: I'm running a 64-bit version of Eclipse, so it's presumably a 64-bit process.

Comment: The Win32 API defines separate `PROCESSENTRY32A` and `PROCESSENTRY32W` structures, and separate `Process32FirstA()` and `Process32FirstW()` functions. The `A`s use 8bit ANSI, the `W`s use 16bit UTF-16. Which ones are JNA's `PROCESSENTRY32` and `kernel.Process32First()` actually mapping to? It makes a difference in how `szExeName` is converted to a `string`. `Native.toString()` takes a `byte[]` array as input, but `szExeName` is a character array, either 8bit or 16bit characters depending on which API is actually being used.

Comment: @Remy presumably the 16 bit versions because `szExeFile` is `char[]`.

Comment: @Remy But it turns out not to be so. Apparently JNA gets this wrong. Calls A functions with W structs.

Comment: @Christopher why did you not include error checking in the code?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I thought it would throw a `LastErrorException` if anything went wrong. As I said, I'm new to JNA.

Comment: No. You have to check for errors. You'll need to read the msdn docs for each function that you call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing options to `Native.loadLibrary` to tell JNA to automatically map to `Process32FirstW` (`W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS` will do that for you).  See how JNA itself loads the `kernel32` library.

The definition of `Process32First` included with JNA's `platform.jar` will actually *only* work with the unicode (`-W`) version due to the definition of the `PROCESSENTRY32` structure, which uses Java `char` for the filename.  The reason you're getting junk is that the encoded byte array of the "ANSI" version has been read into a Java `char` array.  `Native.toString()` is attempting to read from that array, unaware that the data was originally encoded bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The JNA uses [Process32First\Next which is the ANSI version but you need to use the Unicode or UTF-16LE version which is Process32FirstW\NextW.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) This is likely a bug in JNA as it uses the Unicode version of `PROCESSENTRY32` expecting `TCHAR` for `szExeFile` to be UTF-16LE

You may extend Kernel32 as such:

Kernel32.java:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Tlhelp32;

public interface Kernel32 extends com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32 {
    Kernel32 INSTANCE = (Kernel32)Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class, com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    boolean Process32FirstW(HANDLE hSnapshot, Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32 lppe);
    boolean Process32NextW(HANDLE hSnapshot, Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32 lppe);

}
```

Change Processes.java as such:

```
try
{
    snapshot = kernel.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( Tlhelp32.TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, new DWORD( 0 ) );
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry = new PROCESSENTRY32( );
    kernel.Process32FirstW( snapshot, entry );

    do
    {
        processes.add( new Process( Native.toString(entry.szExeFile ), entry.th32ProcessID.intValue() ) );
    }
    while( kernel.Process32NextW( snapshot, entry ) );
}
finally
{
    kernel.CloseHandle( snapshot );
}
```

**Original Answer with woefully abandoned and outdated ANSI:** 
Try

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.sun.jna.LastErrorException;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Tlhelp32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.DWORD;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE;



public class Processes 
    {
        private static final Kernel32 kernel = ( Kernel32 )Native.loadLibrary( Kernel32.class );

        static class Process{
            public String pName;
            public int pID;
            Process(String pName,int pID){
                this.pName = pName;
                this.pID = pID;
            }
        }

        public static ArrayList<Process> getSnapshot( ) throws LastErrorException
        {
            ArrayList<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>( );
            HANDLE snapshot = null;

            try
            {
                snapshot = kernel.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( Tlhelp32.TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, new DWORD( 0 ) );
                PROCESSENTRY32 entry = new PROCESSENTRY32( );
                kernel.Process32First( snapshot, entry );

                do
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[entry.szExeFile.length*2];
                    for(int i=0;i<entry.szExeFile.length;i++) {
                       bytes[i*2+1] = (byte) (entry.szExeFile[i] >> 8);
                       bytes[i*2] = (byte) entry.szExeFile[i];
                    }
                    processes.add( new Process( Native.toString( bytes, "ANSI" ), entry.th32ProcessID.intValue() ) );
                }
                while( kernel.Process32Next( snapshot, entry ) );
            }
            finally
            {
                kernel.CloseHandle( snapshot );
            }

            return processes;
        }
    }
```

Really the only change is converting char[] to byte[] so "ANSI" can be specified.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[entry.szExeFile.length*2];
for(int i=0;i<entry.szExeFile.length;i++) {
   bytes[i*2+1] = (byte) (entry.szExeFile[i] >> 8);
   bytes[i*2] = (byte) entry.szExeFile[i];
}
processes.add( new Process( Native.toString( bytes, "ANSI" ), entry.th32ProcessID.intValue() ) );
```

With above class in Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Processes.Process> curProcesses = Processes.getSnapshot();
    for(Processes.Process curP : curProcesses){
        System.out.println(curP.pName + ":" + curP.pID);
    }
}
```

I get:

[System Process]:0 
System:4
smss.exe:248
csrss.exe:444
csrss.exe:532
wininit.exe:540
services.exe:588
lsass.exe:596
...etc

Comment: That only works if the first argument to Native.toString is of type byte[]. It's of type char[].

Comment: Why do you think the text is UTF-8 encoded? It is not.

Comment: That works for me too :|. Now a follow-up question would JNA thought that was a good idea.

Comment: It isn't UTF-8 encoded. The downvote is valid. The byte arrays would be ANSI encoded. Why the ANSI function is called is anyone's guess. That is a mistake. It's disappointing that the asker has accepted this poor answer. Doesn't anybody here want to do it right?!!

Comment: @ChristopherO'Toole
It looks like a bug in JNA. They are expecting little-endian UTF-16 or what is commonly called Unicode, but they call `Process32First` instead of `Process32FirstW`, so Windows returns the ANSI encoding, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan
ANSI is essentially UTF-8 for the English charset which is apropos here. My solution worked and fixed the problem, sorry about your feelz.

Comment: Now, that's more like it. Head in that direction and you'll get somewhere. A decent solution will be to call Process32FirstW and Process32NextW and stick with UTF-16LE.

Comment: @Motes But you are way off base when you say that UTF-8 is the same as ANSI. That is utter nonsense. If you would fix your answer I'd change my voting. Why do you want to write an answer that you surely know is wrong?

Comment: @ChristopherO'Toole
I don't believe JNA includes `Process32FirstW`, but maybe you could extend it like here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30513928/adding-another-method-to-jna-class-java-kernel32

Comment: You need to explain why you ended up with code like this. Explain the JNA bug. And you went for the wrong fix. There's no excuse for using ANSI in 2016. Use a Unicode encoding. That means calling the W variants. That's how to fix it properly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Indeed, [it's the current year](https://www.reddit.com/r/sjwhate/comments/3poc1z/its_the_current_year_i_cant_believe_its_the/)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I revoked my acceptance as an appeasement. I agree it's not a beautiful answer, but this question hasn't received much attention. And his solution, while perhaps not the best, does indeed at least patch the problem.

Comment: @Motes ANSI could not be avoided when you had to support Win 98, but those days are gone.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Also, with all your criticisms, you might as well make your own answer.

Comment: The other question I linked could show you how to use ProcessFirstW instead if that was your desire, I actually have written some programs with non-ANSI characters in the process name so they wouldn't be printed correctly with this solution.

Comment: @Christopher I'm sure Motes will make the small edits needed to make this a good answer. He's very receptive. I don't want to write an answer because Motes has done the heavy lifting now. All the info is here, some of it only in comments. A minor edit will complete it all.

Comment: @Motes Thanks for the edits, but I wish you'd add some explanatory text. Explain why the changes need to be made, and why the code in the Q fails.

Comment: I take it y'all are still nonplussed.